# Net::ReadTimeout with local URI

Tags: ruby, file

I'm trying to understand why is the following method is blocking my app.

```
url = 'http://192.168.1.33/assets/my_small_pic.jpg'
image_file = open(url).read
```

It's working perfectly when I try it in the console. But when I do it from an API method, it blocks my app and after a long while I have the following error:

```
Net::ReadTimeout (Net::ReadTimeout)
```

What does my app not like my way of reading the file?

Answer (score 1):

I assume you're using **'open-uri**' and the api is a part of the **same RoR** app where you're sending the request to. In this case your app is just being blocked by the **first request** while you **send a second request** to it so the second request gives a timeout. You should see this issue in **development only**. In **production** things will be a bit different since static assets to be served by the Nginx or Apache. Additionally Rails 4 is by default is thread safe in production which means it can serve multiple requests at a time. So if you're on Rails4 then in production calls to other apis will work as well. For Rails3 you would have to explicitly specify `config.threadsafe!`

In general I would recommend you to access resources or make any other API calls from the same app **directly**. It's more efficient. In your example above you can read the file like this:

```
File.read(File.join(Rails.root, 'public/assets/my_small_pic.jpg'))
```

If you still want to send the request then to make it work in development you have to start a new thread similar to this:

```
Thread.new do
  open('http://192.168.1.33/assets/my_small_pic.jpg').read
end
```